# Complex SQL query in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I need to select groups from all user's groups that do not belong to projects of the current user.

1. groups habtm projects
2. projects belongs_to user
3. groups habtm users

The problem is that a group can exist without a project. I understand how to make separate simple queries:

```
@groups = current_user.groups.includes(:groups_projects).where.('groups_projects.project_id' => nil)

@groups = current_user.groups.includes(:groups_projects).where.not('groups_projects.project_id' => current_user.projects.ids)
```

How to make it in one query?

**UPDATE**

According the answer I make the query:

```
@groups = current_user.groups.includes(:groups_projects).where("'groups_projects.project_id' = ? AND 'groups_projects.project_id' NOT IN (?)", nil, current_user.project_ids)
```

But now here is an error:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "groups_projects.project_id"
```

**UPDATE 2**

Answer below is good, but it doesn't do the job for me, so I make it by different way:

```
@groups = current_user.groups - current_user.groups.joins(:projects).merge(current_user.projects)
```

Maybe it's no right way, but it works.

Comment: Use `current_user.projects_ids` instead of `current_user.projects.ids` if you would like to use integrated Rails methods

Comment: @Aleks yes, but not projects_ids, but project_ids. thanks

Comment: hehe, yes, correct, sorry, forgot to delete `s` while copy and pasting

Comment: In your update, you are having the syntax error because of the single quotes around column names, they are not needed.

Comment: @p4sh4 yes, I tried several variants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [can use](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) SQL in `where` clauses representing the `WHERE` part of the underlying SQL statement. In your case it might look like

```
.includes(:groups_projects).where('groups_projects.project_id = ? OR groups_projects.project_id NOT IN (?)', nil, current_user.projects.ids).references(:groups_projects)
```

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "groups_projects"` could you help some more. it's result of query from your answer.

Comment: [If you want to add conditions to your included models you’ll have to explicitly reference them](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes), meaning that when you use `include` with a `where` clause, you need to explicitly reference the table by adding `.references(:groups_projects)` to the end of your statement. Try that.

Comment: yes, now it works, but result is unsuspecting for me( now, if group is part of two or more projects of different users it's displayed.  It should be one more condition: if current user's group is part of current user's project, then it should be not selected, even if it's part of another user's project. It's making me mad today)

Comment: You can add more conditions in the statement to meet all your requirements